# 2 page view using UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios-animations

I am trying to create a TWO-PAGE view same like a open book with curl effect. Sample Image attached here -

[image]

To achieve this, there is a one library named "[leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves)" using which this can be achieved, but this library is obsoleted, and i want to implement same effect using UIPageViewController. **I made a view with single page which we can be easily created using UIPageViewController sucessfully** but i am not getting idea to achieve such kind of functionality using UIPageViewController.

if anyone can give me some idea,guidance,share a link or any help by which i can achieve this functionality using only UIPageViewController then it will help.

Comment: The library you linked seems to have a lot of salvageable code if your goal is to implement your own view.If you want to use `UIPageViewController` you'll be limited by what it is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

you can see http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/ and use or tutorial this project for done work.